# How to Change app_id for Paypal xcode api

Tags: xcode, paypal

I have a log when user finnish payment.
I need to change app_id but i can't to find it.

This is my log

```
Here is your proof of payment:

{
    client =     {
        environment = mock;
        "paypal_sdk_version" = "1.0.5";
        platform = iOS;
        "product_name" = "PayPal iOS SDK";
    };
    payment =     {
        amount = "1.00";
        "currency_code" = USD;
        "short_description" = "Hipster t-shirt";
    };
    "proof_of_payment" =     {
        "adaptive_payment" =         {
            "app_id" = "APP-1234567890";
            "pay_key" = "AP-70M68096ML426802W";
            "payment_exec_status" = COMPLETED;
            timestamp = "2013-07-05T02:20:57Z";
        };
    };
}

Send this to your server for confirmation and fulfillment.
```

Answer (score 3):

@Lmstart, "APP-1234567890" is the app-id provided when you are running the PayPal iOS SDK in its "mock" environment, `PayPalEnvironmentNoNetwork`. If you switch to `PayPalEnvironmentSandbox` or `PayPalEnvironmentProduction` you should instead see an application ID corresponding to your app.

Comment: @vivek are you asking about the `pay_key` shown in the above example of a proof-of-payment record, or the `payerId` that you must provide when creating a `PayPalPaymentViewController`, or something else?

Comment: I am asking about pay_key

Comment: Yes, the pay_key (called `payKey ` in [the Adaptive Payment documentation](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APCallsHeadersAndPaymentTypes/)), is a token associated with a particular *payment* transaction, and *not* a particular *payer*.